# Откуда появилось выражение "дорожная карта"?

Tags: фразеология

Выражение "дорожная карта" активно употребляется в СМИ и официальных документах, но значение его часто темно, не прочитывается. Откуда оно появилось?

Comment: Приведите, пожалуйста, пример употребления этого выражения, в котором его значение "не прочитывается".

Comment: Я прочитывал его всегда буквально, как что-то связанное с указанием пути, дороги, в соответствии с его внутренней формой (связь с существительным "дорога"). Указание на последовательность действий ("план действий, план мероприятий ")не содержится ни в одном из компонентов этого словосочетания, и меня как человека, не знающего ни одного языка, кроме русского, не способного соотнести его с английским прототипом,  употребление сего оборота всегда ставило в тупик., являлось причиной коммуникативного затруднения.

Comment: И, если честно, то мне непонятно, почему нельзя сказать "порядок действий", "последовательность действий", наконец, "план действий".  В употреблении выражения "дорожная карта", мне видится стремление к некоему особому языковому кокетничанью (это относится и ко многим другим английским фразеологическим и  семантическим калькам).

Comment: Совет на будущее: используйте кнопку "правка", чтобы изменить / дополнить вопрос. А мы тогда будем дополнять ответы. По поводу "порядка действий" и т.п. Фразеологизм "дорожная карта" более ёмкий и интересный, по-сути это метафора. По аналогии с проездом из п.А в п.Б "дорожная карта" даёт Вам не один план действий, а целую схему планов: можно достичь цели по такой последовательности, а можно по другим.

Comment: Дорожной картой» называют Указ Президента РФ № 597 о повышении зарплаты…
Дорожная карта - это льготная карта для экономии денег на проезде...
Дорожная карта" - одно из новых понятий, введенных в 2013-ом году в России в связи с глобальной модернизацией образования и науки, здравоохранения, дорожного строительства …
«...по окончании переговоров главы военных ведомств России и Индии подписали дорожную карту развития двустороннего военного сотрудничества…«В дошкольном образовании "дорожная карта" включает целью обеспечить стандарт дошкольного образования к 2018-ому году

Comment: Согласен, что в большинстве приведенных цитат корректность употребления этого фразеологизма вызывает большие сомнения, хотя и подразумевается в основном указанное в ответе значение. Спасибо за примеры.

Comment: Метафоры вообще не должны употребляться в документе. Здесь они могут сыграть роль агнонима, затемняющего смысл сказанного. А.Платонов "Чевенгур":"Больше всего Пиюся пугался канцелярий и написанных бумаг - при виде их он сразу, бывало, смолкал и, мрачно ослабевая всем телом, чувствовал могущество черной магии мысли и письменности».

Answer (score 7):

[Викисловарь](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B0) со ссылкой на словарь Е.В. Бондаревой *"Калькирование языковых единиц как социолингвистический феномен"* говорит, что это калька с английского "road map". Значение этого фразеологизма в русском такое же, как в английском: "план действий, план мероприятий".

Answer (score 2):

Что до "дорожной карты", то мне кажется, что это выражение в российский казенный язык впервые вошло где-то в начале 2000-х годов, а именно - после 2003 года, когда было заключено международное соглашение по урегулированию плестино-израильского конфликта, которое официально было названо, на английском, естественно, "План "Дорожная карта".

Поскольку Россия - страна "властицентричная", здесь несколько раз употребленное высоким начальством выражение, даже не очень удачное или вовсе нелепое, очень быстро становится языковой нормой сначала для ближайших подчиненных начальников, затем - для окружающей их обслуги (включая СМИ), и так, часто, для большинства населения. "Дорожная карта", "контрпродуктивный", "бизнес-процесс"... Часто это именно выражения-кальки.